# add roles to user (Windows authentication)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have two folders in my web application, the first one is for normal_user and the second one is for administrator, to secure them I created two roles in asp.net configuration , everything is okay, but the problem is that I wanna authenticate my user with Windows authentication not Forms authentication, What i'm supposed to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing 1: Denying all users through the web.config file.. Declaring your mode to windows:

```
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="Windows" />
   <authorization>
      <deny users="*" />
   </authorization>
</system.web>
```

In the link below scroll down too : "Authenticating and Authorizing a Group:

Based off of my book, explains all 4 kinds:

http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/ASP-NET-3-5-Windows-Based-Authentication.id-310905.html

Comment: No problem @ben01! If you would like place me as your answer/vote :)

Comment: @ben01, only one check answer can be given btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can go thru [Windows Authentication Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/907hb5w9.aspx) or [Windows Authentication](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94612/Windows-Authentication)

You should chage yours `authentication` section

```
<system.web>
 <authentication mode="Windows"/>
</system.web>
```

> To enable impersonation for your Web application, in the application's
>   Web.config file set the impersonate attribute of the identity element
>   to true, as shown in the following code example.

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  <identity impersonate="true"/>
</system.web>
```

> When you use Windows authentication, user names take the form domainName\userName. >Windows groups are used as roles and they take
>   the form domainName\windowsGroupName. Well known local groups such as
>   Administrators and Users are referenced by using the "BUILTIN" prefix
>   as shown here.

```
 <authorization>   
    <allow users="DomainName\Bob, DomainName\Mary" />  
    <allow roles="BUILTIN\Administrators, DomainName\Manager" />   
    <deny  users="*" /> 
 </authorization>
```

Comment: But my two folders are secured by two roles, how to add a roles to my Windows user in web.config ?

Comment: If you're using Windows Authentication roles are equivalent to the local Groups in which the user is a member, or in the case of a domain, the Active Directory Groups. It doesn't use a RoleProvider.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your own RoleProvider, you'll need to use Forms Authentication. You can, however, use a built-in [ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx) to authenticate your users against Active Directory.